# How to select maximum 7 columns in columnselector?

Tags: datatables, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter widget-columnSelector.js file.

By using columnselector at a time need to select maximum 7 columns.

Because my code have 12 columns in columnselector,If I select 12 columns at a time table going out of the screen.

I need solution By using columnselector select maximum **7** columns.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The columnSelector widget does not do this by default. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the columnSelector widget. Two options will be added in v2.27.0 (not yet released at the time of this post).

- `columnSelector_maxVisible` - set maximum number of visible columns.
- `columnSelector_minVisible` - set minimum number of visible columns.

One caveat is that any disabled columns (not visible in the column selector) are not counted towards this min/max value.

I set up [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mcn8o3yu/13/) which is pointing to the code available in the master branch of my repository. Add a `"columnSelector-disable"` class to any of the columns to experience what I mentioned in the above caveat.

```
$(function() {
  $(".custom-popup").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders'],
    widgetOptions: {
      columnSelector_container: $('#columnSelector'),
      columnSelector_saveColumns: false,
      columnSelector_mediaquery: false,

      // set the maximum and/or minimum number of
      // visible columns (added v2.27.0)
      columnSelector_maxVisible: 3,
      columnSelector_minVisible: 1
    }
  });
});
```